# Accessing global table in Lua 3.2(.1)?

Tags: lua, version, global, lua-table

I'm currently using a pre 2000 version of Lua due to the program I am writing a script on being made in that time. The version I am using is 3.2.1.

I'd like to iterate through all elements of the global environment, but I have yet to find a way how. I'd be glad if somebody can tell me if that is even possible in that version of Lua and if so how to do it. _G is a nil value in that version and I cannot getglobal(name) of the table from global.

I have not found anything regarding global environment iteration on https://www.lua.org/manual/3.2/manual.html due to either me overreading it or it not existing.

Thanks for any reply that could help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `nextvar` to traverse all global variables. Search for it in the [manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/3.2/manual.html). See also [this](https://www.lua.org/manual/2.1/subsection3_7_1.html#S0710).

Here is some sample code that prints all global variables:

```
function allvars()
    local k,v=nil
    while 1 do
        k,v=nextvar(k)
        if k==nil then return end
        print(k,v)
    end
end

allvars()
```

`nextvar` existed from Lua 1.1 to 3.2. It was removed in 4.0 when global variables became entries in an ordinary table that could be traversed with `next`.